# How do ensure that a Core Data Fetched Property is fetched from the context rather than the cache?

Tags: iphone, core-data, fetched-property

I have a managed Object Model that contains 2 Entities.

One of the entities (Lets Call it **EA**) calculates it's properties by referencing some properties in a sub-set of the second entity (Call it **EB**).

Within **EA** I have set up a "Fetched Property" with a predicate that returns the subset of **EB** objects that I need.

When I Delete, Insert an **EB** object or change an **EB** Object I use notifications to ensure that **EA** is kept up to date. So for example after a "save" the **EA** object will recalculate it's properties.

My problem is that when I access the Fetched Property (Which I do **within** the **EB** model class using `[self valueForKey:FetchedPropertyKeyName]`), It appears only to extract the cached version. In other words the first time is fine, but when I add another **EA** object I am not seeing it in the returned array when I access the fetched property. This is most obvious when I delete an object, as then I get a crash due to the fact that this object no longer exists.

The documentation for Fetched Properties says:

> If objects in the destination entity are changed, you must reevaluate the fetched property to ensure it is up-to-date. You use refreshObject:mergeChanges: to manually refresh the properties—this causes the fetch request associated with this property to be executed again when the object fault is next fired.

Sorry if it sounds a dumb question but unfortunately I'm not seeing where I should call `refreshObject:mergeChanges:` ??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The discipline of writing the question made me look closely at the code again so I now have a solution!

I added:

`[[self managedObjectContext] refreshObject:self mergeChanges:YES];`

Into the Observing methods. This causes a fetch to occur, and it's in the awakeFromFetch method that I re-evaluate all my properties and the fetched property now contains the new data as expected.